# How does it affect my node when I get the message: "No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers"

Tags: daemon, rpc, ports

I don't have any ports open and I get the message: "No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers". What does this impact on my node? Can I still connect to my node locally and use its RPC interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this impact on my node?

By *not* forwarding ports, you are preventing access for *external* nodes. Note however, nodes that you *initiate* a connection with can still sync from your node.

> Can I still connect to my node locally and use its RPC interface?

Yes.